# Execute a sudo NOPASSWD command remotely via SSH

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a remote linux system that I can connect to via ssh and public key and then execute the following command:

```
sudo jetty restart
```

This command on this system is configured to allow anyone to execute without the sudo password. I.e. the sudoers file probably looks something like this

```
%develop ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/scripts/jetty
```

This is great as we can execute this script with elevated privileges while keeping everything else locked down. The problem is when trying to execute this command remotely, I am always asked for the sudo password.

```
me@home:~$ ssh -t -i ~/.ssh/identity me@remote.server.com 'sudo jetty restart'
Password: .....? (I don't have the sudo password!)
```

Is there a way I can execute this command remotely?

Comment: "ssh -t -i ~/.ssh/identity me@remote.server.com" lets you login without a password prompt, I presume? Just making sure that the password prompt you are seeing is not just an ssh login and not sudo.

Comment: `requiretty` is off? There is also a `tty_tickets` parameter you wish to examine.

Comment: Yes, when I don't specify the command to execute, ssh logs in with no problem. I'm not sure whether requiretty is on or off but grawity's answer below does the trick.

Comment: When using `ssh -t` a tty is always allocated. Besides, with `requiretty`, `sudo` would fail _before_ asking for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `sudo` is picking the right command; if there's a `/usr/bin/jetty` or such, the sudoers rule won't match. (Note that your `~/.bashrc` and such files are ignored when using `ssh <host> <command>`, so your `$PATH` customizations never happen.)

`sudo /opt/scripts/jetty restart` should work.